# How to convert my Eloquent Collection to JSON?

Tags: php, sql, json, laravel

My database output is this:

```
[{"id":1,"domain":"test","email":"test@mail.com","status":"pending"},{"id":3,"domain":"tester","email":"lorem@ipsum.ml","status":"pending"}]
```

if converted to JSON:

```
[
  {
    "id": 1,
    "domain": "test",
    "email": "test@mail.com",
    "status": "pending"
  },
  {
    "id": 3,
    "domain": "tester",
    "email": "lorem@ipsum.ml",
    "status": "pending"
  }
]
```

I wanted to group them by letters (all alphabets) like this:

```
[
  "a" :{

    }
  "b" :{

    }
  "l" :{
    "id": 3,
    "domain": "lorem",
    "email": "lorem@ipsum.ml",
    "status": "pending"
  }
  "t":{
    "id": 1,
    "domain": "test",
    "email": "test@mail.com",
    "status": "pending"
  },

]
```

So that I can easily show them in the views by just using `{{ $json[$char'] or 'No directories in ' . $char}}`. $char is from the loop `@foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $char)`
[image]

This is from my controller:

```
public function all()
  {
    $data = Subdomain::all();

    return view('directories.all' , ['data' => $data]);

  }
```

and my view is:

```
@foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $char)

  <div class="col-md-3">
    <div class="panel panel-info">
      <div class="panel-heading">
        <h3 class="panel-title">{{$char}}</h3>
      </div>
      <div class="panel-body">

      </div>
      <div class="panel-footer">

      </div>
    </div>

  </div>

  @endforeach
```

This is the var_dump:

```
object(Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Collection)#188 (1) { ["items":protected]=> array(3) { [0]=> object(App\Subdomain)#189 (23) { ["timestamps"]=> bool(false) ["connection":protected]=> NULL ["table":protected]=> NULL ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["keyType":protected]=> string(3) "int" ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["attributes":protected]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["domain"]=> string(4) "test" ["email"]=> string(13) "test@mail.com" ["password"]=> string(4) "test" ["status"]=> string(7) "pending" } ["original":protected]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(1) ["domain"]=> string(4) "test" ["email"]=> string(13) "test@mail.com" ["password"]=> string(4) "test" ["status"]=> string(7) "pending" } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["fillable":protected]=> array(0) { } ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dateFormat":protected]=> NULL ["casts":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) } [1]=> object(App\Subdomain)#190 (23) { ["timestamps"]=> bool(false) ["connection":protected]=> NULL ["table":protected]=> NULL ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["keyType":protected]=> string(3) "int" ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["attributes":protected]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(3) ["domain"]=> string(6) "tester" ["email"]=> string(14) "lorem@ipsum.ml" ["password"]=> string(0) "" ["status"]=> string(7) "pending" } ["original":protected]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(3) ["domain"]=> string(6) "tester" ["email"]=> string(14) "lorem@ipsum.ml" ["password"]=> string(0) "" ["status"]=> string(7) "pending" } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["fillable":protected]=> array(0) { } ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dateFormat":protected]=> NULL ["casts":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) } [2]=> object(App\Subdomain)#191 (23) { ["timestamps"]=> bool(false) ["connection":protected]=> NULL ["table":protected]=> NULL ["primaryKey":protected]=> string(2) "id" ["keyType":protected]=> string(3) "int" ["perPage":protected]=> int(15) ["incrementing"]=> bool(true) ["attributes":protected]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(4) ["domain"]=> string(5) "alpha" ["email"]=> string(14) "alpha@brand.nl" ["password"]=> string(5) "alpha" ["status"]=> string(7) "pending" } ["original":protected]=> array(5) { ["id"]=> int(4) ["domain"]=> string(5) "alpha" ["email"]=> string(14) "alpha@brand.nl" ["password"]=> string(5) "alpha" ["status"]=> string(7) "pending" } ["relations":protected]=> array(0) { } ["hidden":protected]=> array(0) { } ["visible":protected]=> array(0) { } ["appends":protected]=> array(0) { } ["fillable":protected]=> array(0) { } ["guarded":protected]=> array(1) { [0]=> string(1) "*" } ["dates":protected]=> array(0) { } ["dateFormat":protected]=> NULL ["casts":protected]=> array(0) { } ["touches":protected]=> array(0) { } ["observables":protected]=> array(0) { } ["with":protected]=> array(0) { } ["exists"]=> bool(true) ["wasRecentlyCreated"]=> bool(false) } } }
```

Comment: Under what criteria you want to group this data?

Comment: @Hackerman by letters.

Comment: You want to group by the first letter of the email address...

Comment: @Hackerman first letter of the domain. if i have alpha, then it belongs to "a".

Comment: Now, can you post the output of `var_dump($data)`

Comment: I edited and posted the var_dump but the output is like a trash.

Comment: Sorry to bother you but, can you repeat the test but using this: `var_dump($data->all());
`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you want to go Full Laravel, use the power of collections:

```
Route::get('/json', function() {
    $json = '[{"id":1,"domain":"test","email":"test@mail.com","status":"pending"},{"id":3,"domain":"tester","email":"lorem@ipsum.ml","status":"pending"}]';

    $letters = collect(array_combine(range('a', 'z'), array_fill(1, 26, [])));

    $grouped = collect(json_decode($json))->groupBy(function ($item) {
        return $item->email[0];
    });

    dd($letters->merge($grouped));
});
```

And you should get

[image]

Comment: Hi, can you help me how to parse that in view?  ` {{ $json[$char]}}` from my controller `$datax = json_decode($letters->merge($grouped), true);
    return view('directories.test', ['json' => $datax]);`

Comment: Thanks for the answer and idea. Already parsed it in the view.

Answer (score 1):

You don't need JSON, you get a collection with `$data = Subdomain::all();`. Just use `where()` with `like` to search for all rows where email starts with character:

```
@foreach (range('A', 'Z') as $char)
    // Some HTML here.
    @foreach ($data->where('email', 'like', $char) as $row)
        {{ $data->domain}} {{ $data->email }}
    @endforeach
    // Some HTML here.
@endforeach
```

Comment: @VahnMarty well, it's sample code to give you an idea, try to `strtolower($char)` instead of `$char` or something. Try to change `email` to `domain` if you're want to filter by domain name etc (your original question had the same domain for both data sets).

Comment: @VahnMarty you must understand that noone will be able to give you fully working code if they do not know what data you recieve, what error do you get, what column do you want to use to do the search etc.

Comment: I am using this but I don't have any results `@foreach ($data->where('domain', 'like', $char . '%') as $row)
            {{ $row->domain }} 
        @endforeach`

Comment: there must be something wrong with the code you gave, I tried it in my controller, but no output. `  public function all()
  {
    $data = Subdomain::all();

    foreach (range('a', 'z') as $char)
    {
      echo $char . '<br>';
      foreach ($data->where('domain', 'like', $char . '%') as $row)
        {
          echo $row->domain;
        }
    }

  }`

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer. thanks for @alexey for the idea in putting query in blade template.

The answer was simpler like this (Alexey forgot to use the get()),

```
  @foreach ($data->where('domain', 'like', $char . '%)->get() as $row)

        {{$row->domain}}

        @endforeach
```

but I wanted to be clean.
So I created a scope in Model (Subdomain).

```
public function scopeCategory($query, $char)
    {
      $query->where('domain', 'like',  $char . '%')->get();
    }
```

and did this in my blade view:

```
 <div class="panel-body">
        @foreach (\App\Subdomain::category($char)->get() as $row)

        {{$row->domain}}

        @endforeach


      </div>
```

Comment: This doesn't seems right to me because your querying it from view using 26 loops. There could be better ways.

Comment: @Vahn Marty I didn't forgot `get()`, when you're using `\App\Subdomain::category($char)->get()`, you create new query each time. `The Alpha` is right, your code makes 26 queries which is very bad. My code will make just one query, then you'll just work with collection you've already got in memory.